# Calculate specified probability

Tags: statistics

*Question:* Suppose that $T$ is a random variable. Given that $P(-3.3 \leq T \leq 3.3) =.775$, and that $P(T<-3.3)=P(T > 3.3)$, we are to find $P(T < -3.3)$.

How do I begin to solve this?

The answer is .1125

Comment: $K$ should be $T$, right? Do you need to calculate the probability $\Pr\{T<-3.3\}$?

Comment: This is sort of a mess. Maybe go back now and edit it yourself.

Comment: Because the author did not fix typos, I proposed an  edit that is consistent with the comments, and with stating a problem that has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(-3.3 \le T \le 3.3)$ and
$P(T > 3.3) = P(T < -3.3)$ for a random variable $T,$ 
then find $P(T < - 3.3).$

Can you figure out why the probability not in the center has to
be split in half and finish the problem?

Comment: I'm overlooking the lack of thought and attention to detail here because I think this is an important problem. You will see this kind of logic again. Perhaps when using normal tables to figure the rejection region for a two sided test, or to make a confidence interval. It helps to draw a sketch, chop the density function into pieces with vertical lines, and label each chunk with its probability.

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbb P (-3.3<=T<=3.3) = 0.775$

$\mathbb P(T<-3.3)$ indicates probability from -infinity to $-3.3$

$\mathbb P(T>3.3)$ indicates probability from 3.3 to +infinity

Let the $\mathbb P(T<-3.3) = x = \mathbb P(T>3.3)$

$\mathbb P(T<-3.3) + \mathbb P(-3.3<=T<=3.3) + \mathbb P(T>3.3) = 1$

$2x + 0.775 = 1$

$x = 0.1125$

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  In the future, you may wish to write in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which will make your answers easier to read.  But thank you for providing a useful answer here.